# Coldfusion cfselect bind only works when cfdebug is enabled

Tags: coldfusion

I have a cfselect statement that is bound to a remote cfc. It passes the value of another element in the form to the cfc in order to populate the cfselect. I was running this code with cfdebug enabled and it seemed to be working fine, but I found that if I do not have cfdebug enabled nothing is populated. I am not getting any other errors that I know of, and I have tried it in chrome and mozilla - same problem.

Here is my cfselect:

```
<cfselect name="intlRepID" id="intlRepID" required="yes" value="userID" display="businessName" bind="cfc:nsmg.extensions.components.user.getIntlRepRemote({programID})" bindonload="true" />
```

Here is my remote function:

```
<cffunction name="getIntlRepRemote" access="remote" returntype="array" output="false" hint="Gets a list of Intl. Reps. assigned to a candidate">
    <cfargument name="programID" default="" hint="Get Intl. Reps. Based on a list of program ids">

    <cfscript>
        // Define variables
        var qGetIntlRepRemote='';
        var result=ArrayNew(2);
        var i=0;
    </cfscript>

    <cfquery 
        name="qGetIntlRepRemote" 
        datasource="#APPLICATION.DSN#">
            SELECT
                u.userID,
                u.businessName
            FROM 
                smg_users u
            INNER JOIN
                smg_students s ON s.intRep = u.userID
            WHERE
                s.companyid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#CLIENT.companyid#">
            <cfif LEN(ARGUMENTS.programID)>
                AND 
                    s.programID IN ( <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ARGUMENTS.programID#" list="yes"> )
            </cfif>
            AND
                s.active = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="1">
            GROUP BY
                u.userID
            ORDER BY
                u.businessName
    </cfquery>

    <cfscript>
        // Add default value
        result[1][1]=0;
        result[1][2]="---- All - Total of " & qGetIntlRepRemote.recordCount & " International Representatives ----" ;

        // Convert results to array
        For (i=1;i LTE qGetIntlRepRemote.Recordcount; i=i+1) {
            result[i+1][1]=qGetIntlRepRemote.userID[i];
            result[i+1][2]=qGetIntlRepRemote.businessName[i];
        }

        return result;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: What is cfdebug? What version of ColdFusion? Have you called the component to be sure the desired results are being returned?

Comment: with cfdebug off, what do u see when you invoke `nsmg.extensions.components.user.cfc?method=getIntlRepRemote(1)`?

Comment: @BenKoshy - cfdebug is an AJAX debugger that you can run with your code by passing it in the url (url?cfdebug). The correct results are being displayed when cfdebug is on. - I am using Coldfusion 9.

Comment: @Henry - same, if my function gets an empty string as input it returns all records so I tried that too but nothing seems to work unless I have cfdebug enabled.

Comment: @Henry - I just added it

Comment: I realized that its really just how I'm using the page, AJAX is being used to put the form within another page. I tried calling the page directly and it works there, so it's probably an error somewhere else in my code. Now I get to find try to find that :) - Thank you for your replies.